# Change background color on refresh

Tags: php, javascript, random

I want my site to have a different background color for the body every time I refresh the page. Can you please tell me how this would be done using Javascript or PHP? Thank you.

Comment: off-topic! you can ask for help, but not for code!

Comment: @ch4nd4n after reading the Help! i found out this question is actually on-topic! sorry MY bad.

Answer (score 0):

So simple with this function:

#### With PHP

```
<?php

function random_bg() {
    return strtoupper(dechex(rand(0,10000000)));
}

?>

<body style="background-color: #<?php echo random_bg();?>">
```

#### With jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var color = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
    $('body').css('background', color);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this on browser end using JavaScript with something like keep an array of colors and select one from that. Using array of selected colors will ensure that you dont run in to some obscure color that may hamper the readability completely.

```
var bgColors=new Array("#AAAAA", "#FFFFF", "#DDDFFF", "#CCCCCC", "#333333", "#FFCC11", "#FFFFFF", "#DDDD00")

document.body.style.background=bgColors[Math.floor(Math.random()*bgColors.length)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

  $color_list = array("green","red","white"); //colors that you wish

  bg = $color_list[rand(0,count($color_list))];

?>

<body bgclor="<?php echo bg; ?> ">

</body>
```